# Find a table row height and apply padding to a div based on row's height

Tags: javascript

I have a div that have it's content server-generated dynamicaly within a table. I need to have the bottom row on top of the table and I did it with CSS. But, when the content increase it's height, this fourth row covers the first row.
The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="main">
<table id="news">
<tr id="tr1">
<td id="td1">
<fieldset id="fieldset1">Content</fieldset>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr2">
<td id="td2">
<fieldset id="fieldset2">Content</fieldset>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr3">
<td id="td3">
<fieldset id="fieldset3">Content</fieldset>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.main { padding-top: 150px; } /* Making room for 3rd row */
#tr3 { margin-top: -500px; } /* Move it above the other rows */
```

What I need is a way to find the height of #tr3 and to pass this value to both .main's padding and #tr3's margin-top. I've tried to put together something from the solutions I found trough search, but my knowledge is not that extended and what I came up is this:

```
var tr3Height = document.getElementById('#tr3').clientHeight;
var mainPadding = document.getElementById('.main');

function SetAttribute (ObjectID, Value) { 
   document.getElementById('.main').style.paddingTop = tr3Height + "px";
   document.getElementById('#tr3').style.marginTop = -(500 + tr3Height) + "px";
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this is how it should be done, but I have no idea how to finish it. Maybe someone can help by setting me in the right direction. Thank you.

Edit: I forgot to mention: I can't alter the HTML within the .main div, because is server generated.

Comment: Checked your console to see the errors? You're using `getElementById()` slightly incorrectly. Also, ID's should be **unique**.

Comment: All I get from console is: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Is there another way that you've had done it?

Comment: The HTML is completely invalid as is the JavaScript; if you can't change the HTML ID's to be unique, this may be a problem..

Comment: The content of the table changes every few hours/days, so only refreshing the page I can see the new content. I think that on page load should be good.

Comment: As far as I know, the ID

Comment: As far as I know, the ID's are unique. The HTML was only a layout example. This should work in jsFiddle when I press the Run button, right?

Comment: Not a single line of your JavaScript will run, let alone the whole thing... I've addressed everything in an answer anyway, hope this clears it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Current problems:**

- You have multiple elements using the same ID's. ID's should **always** be unique.
- `getElementById('#tr3')` is invalid.
- `getElementById('.main')` is also invalid.
- You can't set `marginTop` on an element which is displayed as a `table-cell`.
- You're not actually ever calling your function (and judging by comments you want it on page load)

---

**Solutions (ordered as above):**

- Change all duplicate ID's in your mark-up to be unique.
- This should be `getElementById('tr3')`.
- Replace the class `main` with an ID `main` and use `getElementById('main')`.
- I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve with this part (at the moment anyway)...
- There's no need for the seperate function if you want it on load, just use w`indow.onload =  function()`..

---

This will solve your load and padding issues (note I've changed the mark-up to have unique ID's - check the jsFiddle below), although as you can see in the comments, your margin change, while registered, will have no effect:

```
window.onload = function(){
   var tableRow3Height = document.getElementById('tableRow3').clientHeight;
   console.log(tableRow3Height); // returns 42
   document.getElementById('main').style.paddingTop = tableRow3Height + "px";
   var tableRow3 = document.getElementById('tableRow3');
   tableRow3.style.marginTop = -500 + tableRow3Height + "px";
   console.log(tableRow3.style.marginTop) // returns -458px, although it won't do anything.
};
```

[**jsFiddle example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gNF9h/4/)